# Piping output to forks in C

Tags: c, fork, dup2

I have a multiple processes in progs and I wish to pipe the output from one process to another sequentially. I believe I have already linked the stdin of a process to the read end of a previous process, and linked the stdout to the write end of the pipe. I still am not seeing an output. Am I missing something with the links here?

```
  int pipeFds[numProg][2];
  
  for (int i = 0; i < numProg; i++) {
    if (pipe(pipeFds[i]) != 0) { // create pipe for each process
      printf("Failed to create pipe!");
      exit(1);
    }
    child_pid = fork();
    if (child_pid == -1) {
      printf("Error while creating fork!");
      exit(1);
    } 
    if (child_pid == 0) {
      if (i == 0) { 
        close(pipeFds[i][READ_END]); // close STDIN first process since it does not read
      } else { 
        // change stdin to read end of pipe for intermediary processes
        close(pipeFds[i]);
        dup2(pipeFds[i - 1][READ_END], STDIN_FILENO);
      }
      dup2(pipeFds[i][WRITE_END], STDOUT_FILENO); // change stdout to write end of pipe
      execvp(progs[i][0], (char *const * )progs[i]);
    } else {
      // parent process stuff
    }
  }
  
  // Close pipes except last pipe for EOF
  for (int i = 0; i < numProg - 1; i++) {
    close(pipeFds[i][READ_END]);
    close(pipeFds[i][WRITE_END]);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember you need to close **all** pipes, in **each** process, for it to work.

Example:

If `numProg=2` you create 2 pipes and 2 child processes. Adding the parent, there a 3 processes running, and in **each of them** you eventually need to close **all** pipes.

For `child_pid==0` you close the `[READ_END]` but never the `[WRITE_END]`.

For `child_pid==1` you do a `close(pipeFds[1])`. You need to specify `[READ_END]` and `[WRITE_END]`.

Then each child process exits via `execvp` which, however, may return control if it fails. From the [man](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp) page:

*The exec() family of functions replaces the current process image with a new process image. .. The exec() functions only return if an error has occurred.*

So you may want to add a `_exit(0);` after `execvp` to ensure each child process exits properly even if `execvp` fails.

The parent process closes all pipes but the last. So in the example of `NumProg=2`, `[READ_END]` and `[WRITE_END]` of `pipeFd[1]` both are never closed.

Lastly, the parent process should `wait` for all child processes to close (using `while(wait(NULL) != -1);`) otherwise you may end up with zombie or orphan processes.

Answer (score 0):

1. your code contains a stray `close(pipeFds[i]);`
2. you have to close the pipes within the `// parent process stuff`.  With your code, every child keeps the `pipeFds` of the previous children open.  E.g.

   ```
    } else {
        // parent process stuff
        if (i > 0)
            close(pipeFds[i - 1][READ_END]);
        close(pipeFds[i - 1][READ_END]);
    }
   ```
3. it might be more effective to have a single `fds[2]` pair instead of `numProg` ones.